# angularJS -npm-debug.log

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

Beginner: 
Trying to set up my work environment with angular yeoman and grunt following this tutorial:
[Learn realtime web apps](https://thinkster.io/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/)
I'm on the first steps. As I run this command:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

I get this error:

> Please include the following file with any support request:
>   /Users/jose/development/angularBlog/npm-debug.log

and then it is all errors after that..hope someone can orient me a bit. 
thanks,
jose

Comment: could you please paste the *entire* error?

Comment: are you running this on linux?